# anyone using Python/XML package

Tags: python, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XML parsing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373707/xml-parsing-in-python)

Which package do you use for XML processing using Python language?
There is a python/xml package: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyxml/
However, it seems no one is maintaining it any more, "out of date"... Is it because it's obsolete or too stable that no maintenance is needed? The current version is built in 2004, which is seven years ago. Does anyone have any experience with it?
Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 3):

Avoid PyXML if possible. It really is out of date as it doesn't even compile anymore on current Python versions, and isn't even all that helpful for handling simple XML.

I'd recommend using [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer cElementTree. http://effbot.org/zone/celementtree.htm

It has good benchmark performance and it is included with Python 2.5 and later. lxml was recommended in another answer and it appears to offer an interface very similar to ElementTree with a few more features: XPath, XSLT, Relax NG, XML Schema support, etc...

A full list of differences can be found here: http://lxml.de/compatibility.html