# Basic Python XML data extraction

Tags: python, lxml

I've been experiencing severe brain farts the last few days, and while I'm sure I could have done this a few months ago, I'm at a total loss as to how to extract the data elements from this output; :(

The return from a `Grp = flickr.groups_getInfo( group_id = gid )` gives

Grp =

```
<group id="34427465497@N01" iconserver="1" iconfarm="1" lang="en-us" ispoolmoderated="0">
    <name>GNEverybody</name>
    <description>The group for GNE players</description>
    <members>69</members>
    <privacy>3</privacy>
    <throttle count="10" mode="month" remaining="3" />
    <restrictions photos_ok="1" videos_ok="1" images_ok="1" screens_ok="1" art_ok="1" safe_ok="1" moderate_ok="0" restricted_ok="0" has_geo="0" />
</group>
```

To extract individual data elements, should it be:

```
group_id = Grp.id
group_name = Grp.name
safe_ok = Grp.restrictions.safe_ok
```

And so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a slightly more verbose syntax needed to extract elements from this item.

```
>>> from lxml import html, etree
>>> example = etree.fromstring("""
<group id="34427465497@N01" iconserver="1" iconfarm="1" lang="en-us" ispoolmoderated="0">
    <name>GNEverybody</name>
    <description>The group for GNE players</description>
    <members>69</members>
    <privacy>3</privacy>
    <throttle count="10" mode="month" remaining="3" />
    <restrictions photos_ok="1" videos_ok="1" images_ok="1" screens_ok="1" art_ok="1" safe_ok="1" moderate_ok="0" restricted_ok="0" has_geo="0" />
</group>
""")

# Attributes can be accessed in two ways:
>>> example.attrib  # Returns a dictionary of key, value pairs
{'iconserver': '1', 'lang': 'en-us', 'ispoolmoderated': '0', 'id': '34427465497@N01', 'iconfarm': '1'}
>>> example.get('id')  # Grabs a specific key in the attribs dict.
'34427465497@N01'

# Children elements are accessed using the getchildren() method:
>>> example.getchildren()  # Returns a list of items.
[<Element name at 0x1007c7140>, <Element description at 0x1007c7190>, <Element members at 0x1007c71e0>, <Element privacy at 0x1007c7230>, <Element throttle at 0x1007c7280>, <Element restrictions at 0x1007c72d0>]
```

One alternate method of extracting children is using xpath:

```
>>> example.xpath(u'//description')  # returns a list of elements which matched the tag name.
[<Element description at 0x1004d82d0>]
```

Accessing items of the Element description are just like the parent node:

```
>>> desc = example.xpath(u'//description')
>>> desc[0].tag
'description'
>>> desc[0].attrib  # This node has no attributes.
{}
```

Other items may have attributes though:

```
>>> example.xpath(u'//restrictions')[0].attrib
{'photos_ok': '1', 'images_ok': '1', 'safe_ok': '1', 'has_geo': '0', 'screens_ok': '1', 'videos_ok': '1', 'moderate_ok': '0', 'restricted_ok': '0', 'art_ok': '1'}
```

Take a look at `dir(example)` for a complete list of methods you can use on a `lxml.etree.Element`.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple XML**

In this question have solution for you:

**Same ask**

[XML parsing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373707/xml-parsing-in-python)

**Reference**

http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom

Answer (score 2):

A variation on @VooDooNOFX 's answer is to use [`lxml.objectify`](http://lxml.de/objectify.html#element-access-through-object-attributes)

```
>>> group = lxml.objectify.fromstring("""<group id="34427465497@N01" iconserver="1" iconfarm="1" lang="en-us" ispoolmoderated="0">
...     <name>GNEverybody</name>
...     <description>The group for GNE players</description>
...     <members>69</members>
...     <privacy>3</privacy>
...     <throttle count="10" mode="month" remaining="3" />
...     <restrictions photos_ok="1" videos_ok="1" images_ok="1" screens_ok="1" art_ok="1" safe_ok="1" moderate_ok="0" restricted_ok="0" has_geo="0" />
... </group>""")
>>> group.get("id")
'34427465497@N01'
>>> group.name
'GNEverybody'
>>> group.restrictions.get("safe_ok")
'1'
>>>
```